# How to cleanly list items in an array - Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am working with Node and Mongoose to create a site with user accounts. I am attempting to create a function that gets all of your followers from an embedded array in the mongoose database, and then renders a page with each user listed. I am able to get the raw array value from the database, example `["follower1", "follower2", "follower3"]`
This is my code for my function that gets that:

```
router.get('/followers/:name', function(req, res, next) {
   User.findOne({username: req.params.name}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log(doc.followers);

    res.render('followers', {title:"Followers", user:req.user, followersnew:doc.followers});
  });
});
```

On the "Followers" page, it displays `followersnew`, as '`follower1,follower2,follower3`' But I want to be able to have it list each user. I tried this:

```
{{#each followersnew}}
  <h3>{{followersnew}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

But nothing shows up.. I'm stuck on how to get each user, and list them cleanly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which rendering engine you use, but that seems like regular handlebars.

This should work:

```
{{#each followersnew}}
  <h3>{{this}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

More info on how to use handlebars:
http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html